# Webscraping In powershell monitor page

Tags: html, powershell, status

I want to be able to monitor my printers status web page and have a script email me when the ink level falls below 25%. Im pretty sure this can be done in Powershell, but Im at a loss on how to do it.

This is the page HTML in question:

```
<h2>Supply Status</h2>

    <table class="matrix">
                <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Supply Information</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Black Toner</td>
        <td>End of life</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cyan Toner</td>

        <td>Under 25%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Magenta Toner</td>
        <td>Under 25%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td>Yellow Toner</td>
        <td>Under 25%</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>

    </table>
    <p>
```

Thanks.

Adam

Answer (score 3):

Building on @Joey's answer, give this a whirl with the HTML Agility Pack.

```
$html = new-object HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument 
$result = $html.Load("http://full/path/to/file.htm") 
$colors = $html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='matrix']//tbody/tr")
$result = $colors | % { 
    $color = $_.SelectSingleNode("td[1]").InnerText
    $level = $_.SelectSingleNode("td[2]").InnerText
    new-object PsObject -Property @{ Color = $color; Level = $level; } | 
        Select Color,Level
}
$result | Sort Level | ft -a
```

This assumes you already have the HTML Agility Pack loaded into PowerShell.  Mine is loaded in my profile as:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom( 
      (join-path $profileDirectory HtmlAgilityPack) 
       + "\HtmlAgilityPack.dll" ) | Out-Null
```

Using the example HTML provided, your output looks like:

[image: output from PowerShell script]

At this point, you have the output and can email it out.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would probably be the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) which you can import in PowerShell. [Lee Holmes](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2010/03/05/html-agility-pack-rocks-your-screen-scraping-world/) has a short article demonstrating a simple example with it. Essentially you're using an XML-like API to access the HTML DOM.

Comment: Would you be able to help me out a bit, I'm very new to all of this.

Comment: Me too. Usually I use examples and the documentation to achieve what I need. But by now it's been quite a while that I used this library, so I cannot help unless I spend all the effort you should be spending instead.